# How to modify a value of a json array from a value but not from a key (Oracle, PL SQL)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

- I want to change my value '4444' to '7727'
- knowing that I only have the old value ('4444') and the new value ('7727') but not the key

```
["4444","5555"]
```

after modification

```
["7727","5555"]
```

Comment: If you want help with an Oracle question, put the Oracle tag on the question. Then all the people who follow the Oracle tag will see your question in there filtered list of open questions, and come and help. But if you add MySQL as well, then the people who look for MySQL questions also come to your question. They have wasted their time, because they may not know much about Oracle!

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. I will remove them

Comment: @RiggsFolly PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language and is not the same as SQL (in the Oracle dialect).

Comment: Yes I know, since I work with oracle I can use sql and pl sql at the same time if for that I put the two tags. I'm new to oracle !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function I made to modify a value of a json array from a value not from a key (old value = '4444', new value = '7727')

```
nmr_cmpt_json := JSON_ARRAY_T.parse(nmrs_cmpts_tab);
i := 0;
    loop
        exit when i> nmr_cmpt_json.get_Size ;
        if nmr_cmpt_json.get_String(i) = '4444' then
            nmr_cmpt_json.put(i, '7727', TRUE);
            nmrs_cmpts_tab:= nmr_cmpt_json .to_string;
            dbms_output.put_line( 'nmr_cmpt_json = ' || nmr_cmpt_json.stringify);
            exit;    
        end if;
        i := i +1;
    end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FOR ORDINALITY` in a `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.json,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS
           idx FOR ORDINALITY,
           value NUMBER PATH '$'
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, json JSON);

INSERT INTO table_name (id, json)
SELECT 1, '["4444","5555"]' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | JSON | IDX | VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ["4444","5555"] | 1 | 4444 |
> | 1 | ["4444","5555"] | 2 | 5555 |

*Note: if you want the index to start from 0 then subtract 1.*

---

If you want to get the values in PL/SQL then you can use `JSON_ARRAY_T`:

```sql
DECLARE
  ja JSON_ARRAY_T := JSON_ARRAY_T.PARSE('["4444","5555"]');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 0 .. ja.get_size - 1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ja.get_number(i) || ' = ' || i );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 4444 = 0
> 5555 = 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6de3a5d377cee43479ef669a831af62d)*